# Microsoft Access (MySQL back end) queries with parameters

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am trying to convert the back end of an Access database to MySQL. So far, I have no problems  converting the tables, and updating the queries with no parameters to pass through queries.

However, I am at a lost at figuring out how to deal with queries with parameters requiring inputs from users.

Anyone could give me some pointers?

Comment: Are you using linked tables? Not all queries need to be passthrough. If you must use a passthrough query, you will need to code to include the parameter.

Comment: Yes they are all linked tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting back-end code that sends data to an Access DB there are few things to look out for.

Dates are handled differently in Access to MySQL.

Access requires that you enclose dates in ## like #05/05/2012#. In MySQL, just enclose them in single quotes, '05/05/2012'.

Column and table names that contain spaces are enclosed in squared brackets like [table name] in Access and backsticks like `table name` in MySQL.

Comment: Yes I did realised there are minor syntax differences.

Answer (score 0):

For linked tables, something like:

```
SELECT ID, AText
FROM LinkedTable
WHERE AText=[Forms]![Form1]![txtText]
```

Should work quite well. There are limitations, in which case you will need a pass-through, but most queries can be written at the Access end just as if the table was a local MS Access table.

To code a pass-through, you might say:

```
Dim objconn As Object
Dim cmd As Object

''Late binding
Set objconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objconn.Open ServerCon

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objconn

cmd.CommandText = "InsertUser"
cmd.Parameters.Append _
   cmd.CreateParameter("UserName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "param1")
```

Comment: So if my original query look something like this:
'PARAMETERS [NameSearch] Text ( 255 );
SELECT GuestName.RefNo, GuestName.GuestName
FROM GuestName
WHERE (((GuestName.GuestName) Like "*"+[NameSearch]+"*"));'
I should add that bit of code on top? I'm very new to this.

Comment: That query will run more or less "as is" in MS Access. You will be prompted for a value for the parameter. It is rarely a good idea to concatenate with + in Access, use &. I am not sure why you are using Like when there are no wildcards. I guess the quotes are to avoid nulls, but why two?

Comment: It should be "asterisk"+[NameSearch]+"asterisk". It's not showing here for some reason.

Comment: Okay, you are losing me here. In what way is this query not working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working. But some of the more complicated queries are a bit slow to run. And I assume converting them to pass through queries should result in performance improvement. Is that correct?

Comment: It may do, alright. For the complicated queries, you can code the parameters.

Comment: @Ed. For basic queries the ODBC driver is able to interpret the Access SQL in a manner to match that of MySql and essentially the queries will still run quickly. However when you bring in Access functions or use syntax that the driver cannot easily translate it has to download the entire table so that Access can apply the query to the information, in these instances it's much better to use either a pass-thru query or an ADODB recordset as Remou has shown above, both of these will be written using the MySql syntax and also run server side, thus increasing the queries performance.

Comment: Thanks Remou & Matt! There are just too many parts that's completely new for me at the moment so I'll do a bit of chewing and testing before I have any more to question. Should references in Access, MySQL and VBA cover everything I might need to know?

Comment: The best advice I can give you about Access is that it is easy, if it is getting complicated, you are doing something wrong. At this stage, do not be tempted to wander into those attractive looking sideways, stick to the main path. After that, yes, there are plenty of references. I found that warily observing the Northwind sample database was helpful. The 2010 version seems to have been beefed up quite a bit, so I am not sure how good the code is, but it was not great in the 2000/2003 versions, however, the ideas are still useful.